Not able to deserialise the Redis data in Spring Boot application
Recently I migrated my Spring Boot application from Java 8 to Java 17. Everything is working fine, except reading the data back from Redis.
I've a populated Redis data which was earlier feeded using a seperate Java 8 application. And earlier it was accessible from my current application when it was running on Java 8. But now I'm not able to read the data from Redis.
Getting the following Error:
org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Could not read JSON: Unexpected character ('¬' (code 172)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false') at [Source: (byte[])"��\u0000\u0005sr\u0000/com.ceb.shl.shlonline.model.content.Assessments\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0000%Z\u0000\u0008isactiveL\u0000\u000Ecandidatelabelt\u0000\u0012Ljava/lang/String;L\u0000\u0008categoryq\u0000~\u0000\u0001L\u0000\u0008criteriaq\u0000~\u0000\u0001L\u0000\u000BcustomersIdt\u0000\u0013Ljava/lang/Integer;L\u0000\u000Bdescriptionq\u0000~\u0000\u0001L\u0000\u0010descriptivelabelq\u0000~\u0000\u0001L\u0000\u0009deviationt\u0000\u0016Ljava/math/BigDecimal;L\u0000\u0007devicest\u0000\u0011Ljava/lang/Short;L\u0000\u000FdisplayCategoryt\u0000\u0010Ljava/util/List;L\u0000\u000CfactsheetsIdq\u0000~\u0000\u0002L\u0000\u000Cfunctiontypeq\u0000~\u0000\u0001L\u0000 generictagq\u0000~\u0000\u0001L\u0000\u0002idq\u0000~\u0000\u0002L\u0000\u0014invalidPenaltyWeightq\u0000~\u0000\u0001L\u0000\u0008labelsIdt\u0000\u0010Ljava/lang/Long;L\u0000\u000FlanguageIsoCodeq\u0000~\u0000\u0001L\u0000\u000BlanguagesIdq\u0000~\u0000\u0002L\u0000"[truncated 2855 bytes]; line: 1, column: 2]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('¬' (code 172)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false') at [Source: (byte[])"��\u0000\u0005sr\u0000/com.ceb.shl.shlonline.model.content.Assessments\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0000%Z\u0000\u0008isactiveL\u0000\u000Ecandidatelabelt\u0000\u0012Ljava/lang/String;L\u0000\u0008categoryq\u0000~\u0000\u0001L\u0000\u0008criteriaq\u0000~\u0000\u0001L\u0000\u000BcustomersIdt\u0000\u0013Ljava/lang/Integer;L\u0000\u000Bdescriptionq\u0000~\u0000\u0001L\u0000\u0010descriptivelabelq\u0000~\u0000\u0001L\u0000\u0009deviationt\u0000\u0016Ljava/math/BigDecimal;L\u0000\u0007devicest\u0000\u0011Ljava/lang/Short;L\u0000\u000FdisplayCategoryt\u0000\u0010Ljava/util/List;L\u0000\u000CfactsheetsIdq\u0000~\u0000\u0002L\u0000\u000Cfunctiontypeq\u0000~\u0000\u0001L\u0000 generictagq\u0000~\u0000\u0001L\u0000\u0002idq\u0000~\u0000\u0002L\u0000\u0014invalidPenaltyWeightq\u0000~\u0000\u0001L\u0000\u0008labelsIdt\u0000\u0010Ljava/lang/Long;L\u0000\u000FlanguageIsoCodeq\u0000~\u0000\u0001L\u0000\u000BlanguagesIdq\u0000~\u0000\u0002L\u0000"[truncated 2855 bytes]; line: 1, column: 2]
My Redis Config looks like this:
   @Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
    redisTemplate.setDefaultSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);

    redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(objectMapper()));
    redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(objectMapper()));

    return redisTemplate;
}

@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.activateDefaultTyping(mapper.getPolymorphicTypeValidator(),
            ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);
    return mapper;
}
@Bean
public StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate (RedisConnectionFactory cf) {
    StringRedisTemplate redisTemplate = new StringRedisTemplate();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(cf);
    return redisTemplate;
}

and I'm fetching the data using the following piece:
return (Assessments)hashOps.get(cacheKeys.getCacheAssessmentKey(), String.valueOf(id));

I was using StringRedisSerializer earlier, and have used the GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer and the mentioned ObjectMapper, but the error remains the same.
